# wrong Grid view selection

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

i have a page that contain 3 grid view

first one :

```
<cc1:Grid ID="Grid2" runat="server" FolderStyle="~/Styles/grand_gray" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoPostBackOnSelect="true"
       AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowAddingRecords="false" AllowColumnResizing="true" AllowPageSizeSelection="true" Width="100%" OnSelect="Grid2_Select">
        <Columns>
            <cc1:Column DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
            <cc1:Column DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
            <cc1:Column DataField="partici" HeaderText="partici" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
            <cc1:Column DataField="publicationName" HeaderText="publication Name" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
        </Columns>
        <ScrollingSettings ScrollWidth="100%" />
    </cc1:Grid>
```

second one :

```
<cc1:Grid ID="Grid3" runat="server" FolderStyle="~/Styles/grand_gray" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" AutoPostBackOnSelect="true"
       AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowAddingRecords="false" AllowColumnResizing="true" AllowPageSizeSelection="true" Width="100%" OnSelect="Grid3_Select">
        <Columns>
            <cc1:Column DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
            <cc1:Column DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
            <cc1:Column DataField="partici" HeaderText="partici" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
            <cc1:Column DataField="publicationName" HeaderText="publication Name" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
        </Columns>
        <ScrollingSettings ScrollWidth="100%" />
    </cc1:Grid>
```

third one

```
<cc1:Grid ID="Grid1" runat="server" FolderStyle="~/Styles/grand_gray" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoPostBackOnSelect="true"
       AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowAddingRecords="false" AllowColumnResizing="true" AllowPageSizeSelection="true" Width="100%" OnSelect="Grid1_Select">
        <Columns>
            <cc1:Column DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
            <cc1:Column DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
            <cc1:Column DataField="partici" HeaderText="partici" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
            <cc1:Column DataField="publicationName" HeaderText="publication Name" HeaderAlign="left" Align="left" ></cc1:Column>
        </Columns>
        <ScrollingSettings ScrollWidth="100%" />
    </cc1:Grid>
```

and when the user select any row from any one of them from the code behind he go to another page depend on the data of each one of them 
the problem is : if select the first one the code work well 
then i use the back button of the browser and select row from the second or third grid 
the selected row still the one of the first grid

```
protected void Grid1_Select(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Hashtable h in e.RecordsCollection)
        {
            string date = h["date"].ToString();
            string description = h["description"].ToString();
            string partici = h["partici"].ToString();
            string publicationName = h["publicationName"].ToString();
            Session["date"] = date;
            Session["description"] = description;
            Session["partici"] = partici;
            Session["publicationName"] = publicationName;

            Response.Redirect("Publications_View.aspx");
        }
    }

protected void Grid2_Select(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Hashtable h in e.RecordsCollection)
        {
            string date = h["date"].ToString();
            string description = h["description"].ToString();
            string partici = h["partici"].ToString();
            string publicationName = h["publicationName"].ToString();
            Session["date"] = date;
            Session["description"] = description;
            Session["partici"] = partici;
            Session["publicationName"] = publicationName;

            Response.Redirect("Publications_View.aspx");
        }
    }

protected void Grid3_Select(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Hashtable h in e.RecordsCollection)
        {
            string date = h["date"].ToString();
            string description = h["description"].ToString();
            string partici = h["partici"].ToString();
            string publicationName = h["publicationName"].ToString();
            Session["date"] = date;
            Session["description"] = description;
            Session["partici"] = partici;
            Session["publicationName"] = publicationName;

            Response.Redirect("Publications_View.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Note : if the first time i select the second or the third grid the code work well till i select row from the first grid , then the problem happen again and only the row from the first grid appear whatever which grid i select

any help ??

Comment: Have you tried destroying these `Session` values upon landing and using them in `Publications_View.aspx`? Try that and see if the problem persists?

Comment: the problem not in the session values , the problem if i select row from Grid2 >> in the code behind i should move to grid2_select , but what happen actually i go to grid1_select

Comment: I see. Seems like it is not binding it correctly for some reason. How do you Bind the data to these Grids?

Comment: from sqlserver connection

Comment: Do you have anything setting up the data in the `Page_Load` event?

Comment: No the page load method is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by adding a button that return me back to the original page 
then if i choose the second or the third grid it bind well

that didn't solve the problem actually but i had to go around it

so i think the problem in the back button of the browser ( page cash or something like that )